# How to get the id & title of a DIV element, using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an element:

```
<div id="Form" title="Disability Form</div>
```

I am trying to get both the id and the title, formatted as such:

```
id: Form
title: Disability Form
```

I'm also trying to use pure Javascript. This is what I have been playing with so far:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for(i=0; i<= x.length; i++)
{
   console.log(x[i].innerText);
}
```

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: `x[i].id` will give you the id and `x[i].getAttribute('title')` will give you the title

Comment: that is not valid HTML: close the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistakes that you have made

1. `<=` should be changed to `<`
2. Didn't close the tag properly

To get the `id` you can use `element.id`

To get the `title` you can use `element.getAttribute('title')`

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for(i=0; i< x.length; i++)
{
   console.log(x[i].innerText);
   console.log('id : ' + x[i].id);
   console.log('title : ' + x[i].getAttribute('title'));
}
```

```html
<div id="Form" title="Disability Form"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `el.id` to get ID and `el.getAttribute('title')` to get the title attribute value.

Also you did not close the title attributes tag in your HTML...

```js
let divs = [...document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')]

divs.forEach(div => {
  div.hasAttribute('id') ? console.log(`id: ${div.id}`) : false;
  div.hasAttribute('title') ? console.log(`title: ${div.title}`) : false;
})
```

```html
<div id="Form" title="Disability Form"></div>
```

Comment: if you know to get the element by `id`. Then what is the point for getting the id again? :P